# Gnome sending keyboard shortcuts to an application

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, gnome, xorg

I would like to send key board shortcuts from my wm (gnome) to an application (specifically Emacs).

for example If I press <kbd>Some-prefix-key</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> then I would like <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> to be passed to Emacs irrespective of window that is currently active

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to put something together using [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml). Specifically, it looks like you'd be able to use [command chaining](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#command_chaining) to send a keystroke to a window with a particular name/class, and bind that script to a key combination using Gconf (it's been a while since I used Gnome, so I have no idea how you'd go about doing that these days).